# Get Last Release Version In Maven

Tags: maven

I have this problem using  the `japicmp` API, but it's probably a problem with every plug-in to compare APIs.

Let's say I have defined the `japicmp` Maven plug-in the following way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.siom79.japicmp</groupId>
    <artifactId>japicmp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <oldVersion>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <version>${lastBaseVersion}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
        </oldVersion>
        <newVersion>
            <!-- snip -->
        </newVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The problem here is the `lastBaseVersion` property. Because of course I don't want to maintain yet another version field in my *pom.xml*. However I can't find out how to configure the plug-in to just use the latest release, even though to me that's the default use case.

<s>[This post](http://massol.myxwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Blog/ByeByeCLIRRWelcomeRevapi) uses `xwiki.compatibility.previous.version` for the `revapi` API, but I can't figure out where that value comes from.</s> [Found it](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-commons/blob/master/pom.xml), it's a manually maintained property, so it doesn't help my case.

How do I compare the API of my project against the latest release?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) which has a [released-version](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/released-version-mojo.html) goal which looks like what you need.

Comment: Can you tell me how it's used? I tried added it [as stated here](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html), so now what? `${releasedVersion.version}` is stil null. How do I access the value of the property?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default maven property that automatically contains the last released version. The maven plugin must lookup all versions and filter out the last one. The point is that you might also release candidates like e.g. 1.0.0-RC1 and it should be up to the user to decide if 0.0.9 or 1.0.0-RC1 is the last "released" version.

But [japicmp](http://siom79.github.io/japicmp/) can automatically fetch the latest version from the repository. You just have to leave out the `<oldVersion/>` block in the configuration. It then takes the latest version without SNAPSHOT. You can optionally provide a regular expression that helps to figure out which version to take: `oldVersionPattern`.